# (LXD) LXC container not starting services automatically

Tags: lxc, lxd

Using: `Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64
       LXD 2.0.0`

I have several containers (all of them running "alpine-edge") in which I'm running lighttpd + mysql.

The problem is that each time I restart the containers I have to restart manually those services as they don't start automatically.

What do I need to do to fix that?

**UPDATE**

The temporally work-around that I'm using is to:

`lxc exec alpine-edge service lighttpd start`

from the parent OS (inside an init script). But I believe there should be a way to do it automatically inside the container, so if I manually reboot it (the container), I don't have to execute that command each time.

Comment: Have you enabled these services on the containers (as in `service enable <service-name>`)?

Comment: No, I haven't. This is what it returns: `service enable lighttpd` : `service: service 'enable' does not exist`.

Comment: That should've been `service lighttpd enable`; sorry.

Comment: Tried that too, but it reports: "enable" unknown function. I think is because alpine has no such function.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I'm learning this as I go along. So Alpine uses `OpenRC` instead of `systemd`. From this [cheatsheet](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet) that I found, does `rc-update add lighttpd default` work?

Comment: Yes! you go it... please make your comment an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alpine Linux uses OpenRC for its init system](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System). The basic commands to interact with it are

```
rc-update add <service> [runlevel]
```

adds `service` to the init sequence (similarly to `systemd`'s `systemctl enable <service>` in Ubuntu 15.04 and forward);

```
rc-update del <service> [runlevel]
```

stops `service` from starting during system init (similarly to `systemd`'s `systemctl disable <service>`);

```
rc-service <service> [start stop restart]
```

manages currently running services (similarly to `systemd`'s `systemctl [start stop restart] <service>`, or equivalently `/etc/init.d/service [start stop restart]` which works in both `systemd` and OpenRC).

More information can be found on the Alpine Wiki page I linked to above, and a cheatsheet for OpenRC-`systemd` translation is available [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet).